# How to manage a session in memory without using local/sessionStorage with React?

Tags: reactjs, session, axios

This is probably a duplicate question, but I'm struggling to find what I need. What I'm trying to achieve is a "session" that stays live until the user logs out. What I need to store in this session is `username` of logged user, and possibly `isloggedIn` boolean flag to use in my router. Previously, I was using `sessionStorage` while developing the app, but now that it's time for go-live I will need a more secure approach. My idea is to simulate sessionStorage but in memory. I need a `session` object that will hold the aforementioned information and will not reset its state on component re-render or whenever I manually change the URL route in the URL bar of the browser. I tried using `static` attributes in a method, but it looks like the `import` of the class in the application is reloaded every time the state of the static attributes is reset. I'm using `axios` as my HTTP client and JWT tokens as authentication for server requests, however I would like to use the session object to manage the routing of the app. I look forward to you replies. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you implemented the functionality on the server?

Comment: @hellogoodnight, thanks for your reply. The server api is different from the client-side api. It's implemented using Quarkus by another colleague. I'm just using it.